# Dojo 1.6 Deferred chaining and hitching issue

Tags: javascript, dojo, chaining, deferred

I got a minor problem with hitching and chaining a deferred ajax request in Dojo 1.6. The code looks like

```
    login : function(data) {            
        var def = lang.hitch(this.authenticate, this.authenticate(data));
        console.log(def); // [I]
        return def;
    },

    authenticate : function(data) {
        require([ "dojo/Deferred", "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/_base/lang",
                "dojox/encoding/digests/MD5" ], lang.hitch(this, function(Deferred, xhr,
                lang, MD5) {
            var data2send = lang.mixin(data, {
                action : "authenticate",
                password : "21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3",
                userId : data.username
            });

            return xhr(this.handlerUrl, {
                handleAs : "json",
                method : "POST",
                sync : false,
                data : data2send
            });
        }));
    }
```

where login() is invoked. Imho, it should return a Deferred-object which resolves after the ajax-request in authenticate() finishes. Therefore, the logging in [I] should give me a Deferred-promise, but Firebug is logging the return value as function(). I hope anyone can help.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Another question is, why def becomes the object, which is given by the first argument of lang.hitch. E.g. in the code above the log gives me "function()". When I change the first argument to "this", the log gives me the "this"-object ("Object {...}") itself. I assumed the mechanism of hitch DOES NOT influence the returned value, BUT ONLY hitches the scope into the 2nd argument (which is the called function). Am I wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

Code finally looks like this:

```
define([ "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/Deferred",
    "dijit/_Widget" ], function(lang, declare, Deferred) {
return declare("LoginController", null, {
    handlerUrl : "sessionHandler.php",
    constructor : function(kwArgs) {
        lang.mixin(this, kwArgs);
    },

    login : function(data) {
        def = new Deferred();
        auth = this.authenticate(data);
        auth.then(function(success) {
            if (success.success == true) {
                def.resolve(true);
            } else {
                def.resolve(false);
            }
        }, function(err) {
            def.resolve(false);
        });
        return def;
    },

    authenticate : function(data) {
        var def = new Deferred();
        require([ "dojo/request/xhr" ], lang.hitch(this, function(xhr) {
            var data2send = lang.mixin(data, {
                action : "authenticate",
                userId : data.userId
            });

            xhr(this.handlerUrl, {
                handleAs : "json",
                method : "POST",
                sync : false,
                data : data2send
            }).then(function(data) {
                def.resolve(data);
            }, function(err) {
                def.reject(err);
            });

        }));
        return def;
    }
});
});
```

I didn't accomplish to get around that async call of require without setting a Deferred in front. Thus, the Deferred constructor has to be initially loaded within the define statement, so I don't need to asynchronically require it within my functions.